# Display Ad on Specific Categories

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I want to display the ad only in specific categories. Can anyone help me here's the code to display the ad on all single posts/

```
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/ads/below-head' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will display the ad on all posts belonging to the categories listed in the array:

```
<?php
global $post;
if ( in_category( array('news', 'cats', 'dogs'), $post->ID ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/ads/below-head' );
} ?>
```

Comment: I edited it to work outside the Loop, give it a try. To be clear, you want to display the ad on posts, not category archives right?

Comment: It was working, I'm sorry I've cleared the CDN cache.

Comment: Hi, If I don't want to display the ad in these categories (news, cats, dogs? Can you provide the code, please?

Comment: Certainly, just add an exclamation mark like so: `if ( !in_category( array('news', 'cats', 'dogs') ) )`